# call reference / deployment function in property name value in ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create Sql server and Sql database in single ARM Template like as below

Sql Server -- Using Linked Template Approach with type resources deployments

Sql Database  -- A new resource section to create database that depends on linked template name.

Below is my Partial ARM template Script (Only Resources Section)

```
 "resources": [
{
  "name": "sqlServerDeployment",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[parameters('sqlserver_Templatepath')]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parametersLink": {
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "uri": "[parameters('sqlserver_parameters_Templatepath')]"
    }
  }
},
{
  "comments": "If Elastic Pool Name is defined, then curent database will be added to elastic pool.",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
  "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
  "name": "[concat('SampleSqlServer1-Test','/', parameters('databasename')[copyIndex()])]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "tags": "[parameters('tagsArray')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('skutier')]",
    "tier": "[parameters('skutier')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
    "sampleName": "[parameters('databasename')]",
    "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]",
    "elasticPoolId": "[if(not(empty(parameters('elasticPoolName'))),reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools',parameters('elasticPoolName')),'2014-04-01'),'')]"
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "createDatabases",
    "count": "[length(parameters('databasename'))]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [ "sqlServerDeployment" ]
}
]
```

**My Query:**

Currently I am hardcoding Sql Server name(SampleSqlServer1-Test) which ever I am passing in **sqlserver_parameters_Templatepath** in Sql database resource section.

```
       "name": "[concat('SampleSqlServer1-Test','/', parameters('databasename')[copyIndex()])]",
```

But how can I fetch same Sql server  Name automatically from above parameters template/output of that template and put it to Name property value of Sqldatabase ? Is it possible to call reference function in Property "Name" value. Something like below

```
       "name": "[concat(reference/resourceId(<output of sqlServerDeployment>).SQLSERVERNAME,'/', parameters('databasename')[copyIndex()])]",
```

Is it possible to call deployment function with properties and its parameters? say sqlservername is parameter name in linked template parameters file.something like below.

```
    "name": "[concat(deployment().properties.parameters.sqlservername,'/', parameters('databasename')[copyIndex()])]",
```